# Plotting line in Linechart with values taken from the textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I've been struggling with my big project since a while, but thanks to your help here on stackoverflow, I managed to done 90% of the work very fast. Thank you for that, you are AWESOME!

Now, I have my final problem, and that is, plotting one line that is taken from the values of the textarea.
Here is my code:

```
$(function () {
var chart;
var params = getParams(document.location.search); 
var title= "Graphical representation";  
var subtitle= "Options";

var yaxis= "Increasing in %";

var xvalues = [];
if(params.hasOwnProperty("xvalues")) 
{
      if(params.xvalues != "") 
      {
        xvalues = CSVToArrayStr(params.xvalues, ',');
      }
}
else 
{
  params.xvalues= [ '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010'];
  xvalues = CSVToArrayStr(params.xvalues, ',');
}


// Drawing the first sample
     var series = Array();
 var sample = {};
sample.name = 'Sample1';
sample.data = [1.6, 3.9, 3.3, 4.0];
series.push(sample);

 //Calculating the 2nd sample using math formula 
    function calc(data) { 
    ret = []; 
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
    data[i] = parseFloat(data[i]); 
    ret[i] = (3.5 + data[i] + 0.5 * (data[i] - 3)); //parse the string to float
    ret[i] = Math.round(ret[i] * 100) / 100;   // rounding to 2 decimals
 } 
   return ret; 
 }

//Drawing the second sample according to the math formula
var stapka = {};
stapka.name = 'Sample2';
 stapka.data = calc(sample.data); // - calculated data
 series.push(stapka);


//Taking value from the textarea
      $.valHooks.textarea = {
  get: function( elem ) {
  return elem.value.replace( /\r?\n/g, "\r\n" );
    }
};


//Transfering values from the textarea to array
var  sample3 = {};
sample3.data = $('textarea').val();
sample3.data = sample3.data.split(",");



if(params.hasOwnProperty("values_serie1")) {
    if(params.values_serie1 != "") 
    {

        series = getSeries(params);



   // The following code is PROBLEMATIC         


var result = {};
result.name = 'Calculated values';
result.data = calc(sample3.data); //here seems to be the problem
series.push(result);


    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'line',
        },
        title: {
            text: title,
            x: -20 //center
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: xvalues[0]
        },

        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: yaxis
            },

        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'<\/b><br/>'+
                  'Year ' + this.x +': Rate '+ this.y + '%';
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right'
        },

       series: series

  });
 });
});
```

I know it's a long code but please take a look at the code where it's PROBLEMATIC.
Here is what this code need to do:

1. Plot the first line according to the provided sample data
2. Plot the second line according to the provided math formula
3. User enters values for the first line
4. The chart draws the first line
5. The chart draws AUTOMATICALLY the second line, according to the provided formula (which is my problem)

I can't figure out where is my mistake, everything is working... The 2 samples are drawn successfully, the inputted values (for the 1st line) are drawn also successfully, but when I need to calculate them for the 2nd line, they don't want to appear on the chart :/

Here is the whole code with the HTML
http://jsfiddle.net/Avramoski/LsTet/2/

And here is image of how I want to look like...
http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/17/tbjm.png

Please help me, this is extremely important to me.
Thanks a million!

Comment: you should tag [tag:javascript] and [tag:jquery] in your question. not only [tag:highcharts]

Comment: Where is defined function `getParams()`? There is error reported `Uncaught ReferenceError: getParams is not defined.`

Comment: I don't really know Sir, I just copied the code from other site (plotvar.com) and modify it... You think that this function may be the problem? But it's working when for ex. I put on the PROBLEMATIC line: `result.data = calc(sample.data)` . Any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: Can you use console.log(JSON.stringify(series)) and paste what you receive?

Comment: Here what is says in console: `TypeError: data is undefined`
I've created a live example of the code on my website, you can check it here: [TEST](http://test.pua.mk/) 
Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the webmaster of [plotvar.com](http://www.plotvar.com). I'm glad to hear you used it for your line graph maker code stuff ;)

You're not really using correctly the getSeries and getParams functions.
These functions are used for the handling of multiples series (retrieving it from url).

Anyway, I've made a small sample of a working code for you.

Adapt it for your needs ;)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Amortization</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="all" />

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="./js/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="./js/modules/exporting.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="./js/utils.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



</head>
<body>
<h3 align="center">Calculating for different values:</h3>


 <form action="#container"   method="GET">
        <div class="item" align="center"><label for="xvalues" >Insert years for X axis</label><br/><input type="text" name="xvalues" placeholder="2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011"></div>

        <div class="item_expandable" style="display:none" align="left"><label for="serie1">Inflation :</label><input type="text" name="serie1" placeholder="Инфлација"> </div>

        <br/>
        <div align="center">
 <label for="values_serie1" >Put the inflation rate:</label><br/><textarea  id="inflacija" rows="4" name="values_serie1" placeholder="1.6, 3.9, 3.3, 4, 2.5, 2.8"></textarea></div>

<div align="center">
<button>Calculate the result</button>
</div>
        <br/>
       <br/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    var chart;

    var params = getParams(document.location.search); 

    var title= "Graphical representation of inflation and interest rate";   
    var subtitle= "Options";

    var yaxis= "Increasing in %";

/*Array xvalues... if there are inserted values in the field for the years, we take them and convert to string*/
    var xvalues = [];
    var yserie = "Foo";
    var yvalues = [];
    if(params.hasOwnProperty("xvalues")) 
    {
          if(params.xvalues != "") 
          { 
            xvalues = CSVToArrayStr(params.xvalues, ',');

          }
    }

    if(params.hasOwnProperty("serie1")) {
        if(params.serie1 != "") {
            yserie = params.serie1;
        }
    }

    if(params.hasOwnProperty("values_serie1")) {
        if(params.values_serie1 != "") {
            yvalues = CSVToArrayInt(params.values_serie1, ',');
        }
    }
    alert("xcalues : " + xvalues + "\nyserie : " + yserie + "\nyvalues : " + yvalues);

    var inflatdata = yvalues[0].slice(0);
    var inflatserie = "inflat"; 
    for(var i = 0; i < inflatdata.length; i++) { 
     inflatdata[i] = parseFloat(inflatdata[i] + 5); 
     // here we parse our string to float
     //inflatdata[i] = (3.5 + inflatdata[i] + 0.5 * (inflatdata[i] - 3));
     //inflatdata[i] = Math.round(inflatdata[i] * 100) / 100;
    }

    console.log(JSON.stringify(xvalues));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(yserie));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(yvalues));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(inflatserie));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(inflatdata));
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

//Options for desigining the chart
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'line',
            },
            title: {
                text: title,
                x: -20 //center
            },


            xAxis: {
                categories: xvalues[0],
                lineWidth: 1
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: yaxis
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }],

                lineWidth: 1,
                 lineColor: '#92A8CD',
                 tickWidth: 3,
                 tickLength: 6,
                 tickColor: '#92A8CD',
                 minorTickLength: 3,
                 minorTickWidth: 1,
                 minorTickColor: '#D8D8D8',

                 tickInterval: 2,
                minorTickInterval: 1,
                minorGridLineColor: '#ADADAD',
                minorGridLineDashStyle: 'LongDashDot'
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'<\/b><br/>'+
                      'Year ' + this.x +': Rate '+ this.y + '%';
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -10,
                y: 100,
                borderWidth: 1
            },

                 credits: {
                position: { 
                   align: 'left',
                   x: 20,
                   y: -7
                },
                text: 'Uist Design Team',
                href: 'http://uist.edu.mk'
            },

            series: [{
                name: yserie[0],
                data: yvalues[0]
            }, {
                name: inflatserie,
                data: inflatdata
            }]
 });
    });

});

</script>


    </div>
   </div>

 <div id="container"style="min-width: 100px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

  </div>
</body>


    </div>
   </div>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

For you information, there's also a "secret" [equation line graph tool](http://www.plotvar.com/plotequation.php) on my website, maybe it could also helps.

Comment: OMG, you Sir deserve a medal! AWESOME! I am big fan of your website, and constantly using it... Btw the above code works like a charm, this is what I am talking about! Thanks a million! Also, I am sure that the equation line graph will be really helpful for me in future... Now it remains one tiny problem with the x values... They appears in [THIS](http://imageshack.com/a/img838/2568/afj7.png) format. Any idea how to fix this? Thanks again :)

Comment: Fixed on the answer, just have to replace xvalues by xvalues[0].